# Layout landscape mode and Categories of layout folders

Tags: android, android-layout

I created following layout folders.

```
res/layout-sw320dp
res/layout-sw480dp
res/layout-sw600dp
res/layout-sw720dp
```

It is ok, layout from corresponding smallest width in dp folder are triggered.

Is it sufficient to create these four folders and our app will looks fine on any density screen or any size screen ? Plz explain this in some detail.

To create layout for landscape mode. what can i do with this ? 
what is the use of multi port ui using fragments ? Is it used for landscape and port-rate layout in one xml file ?

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: You can make different layouts for landscape mode (i,e,: with the Views horizontally arranged) and put them in `res/layout/...-land`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the layouts in `/res/layout` are applied to both `portrait` and `landscape` device screeens.

For example you have `main.xml`

```
/res/layout/main.xml
```

you just need to add a new folder `/res/layout-land`, copy `main.xml` into it and make the needed adjustments, and so on for all of your `layout` files.

[image]

You just need to have same files for land and portrait but with different folders and of course with different modifications.

Hope this to help!

Comment: Yes. it is great library.  But i didn't know that with this library we don't need to create different layout folders. and can you tell me somthing about landscape mode with swxxxdp. and multi port as i asked in question ?

Comment: I dont understand clearly what is the problem with library sorry.. i think that is good for your case because if you set for example width of some Button to be 30% of you screen. The button will look the same of all screen etc.. 30% of landscape screen 30% of portrait screen and so on.

Comment: If we have 5 buttons on a portrait  in vertical manner. it is ok , percentage will work fine. When we change to landscape mode. then last 2 or 3 buttons will be out of screen. for this we will have to create a folder for landscape layouts. so how can i create it ?